# Multiple instances of same image & positioning

Tags: css, html, position, multiple-instances

I'm wanting to position the same image several times on the same page.  I created a div for this image, but I'm not sure what the best way is to position it each time.  I'm a beginner, and I'm hoping this is something relatively simple.  Is there a better way to go about this?  I did have all the 'arrows' in the html part, but it seemed pretty clunky.  Thanks for any help!!!  By the way, this example is just showing 1 instance.

```
div.arrow  
{
width:17px; 
height:16px;
background-image: url("images/resumearrow");
}

<div class="arrow">
<img style= "position:absolute; top:13px; left:-19px; width:17px; height:16px;"></div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're probably going to want to use the CSS property `background-image` (and the shorthand `background`) rather than a div with an image embedded in it.

Here is a simple example:

**HTML**

```
<ul>
    <li>Apples</li>
    <li>Oranges</li>
    <li>Bananas</li>
</ul>
```

​
**CSS**

```
li {
    height: 50px;
    padding-left: 60px;
    margin: 10px;
    background: url(http://placehold.it/50x50) no-repeat;       
}​
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/ySsAg/)

Answer (score 0):

It is difficult to learn what you are trying to do exactly, but I figure you are looking to put an arrow at each instance of [something div].  Have you looked into setting background-url for the class of div you want to apply this arrow to?  If it is something else, how about setting a background on the page and making it repeat down in the y direction only.  This will repeat the arrow every x pixels, where x is the height of the image.

See this for reference: http://www.techforluddites.com/2010/02/thesis-replacing-list-bullets-with-images-using-css.html

Comment: I see what you mean with the repeating arrow, but the paragraphs vary in height.  I ended up going with the unordered list option.  Thanks so much for you help!

Comment: Just so you know, you do not have to make the paragraphs into a list. You can apply the background-url to any object.  It is not limited to li tag.  Just remember to give it padding, otherwise the paragraph will be on top of the background, and also set the repeat to no repeat.

Answer (score 0):

You're partway there, but I've created an example here that shows a working example: http://jsfiddle.net/u8Bww/2/

The `.arrow` element should be set to `display:block;`.  Since I've got text within the `<div class="arrow">Text</div>` HTML, I've used a combination of techniques to hide it from view so the background image shows through: `text-indent: -1000px; color: transparent; font-size: 0px;`.

You can now use the `.arrow` class anywhere you need to show the image.

As for positioning, I've included some examples of inline CSS to do this, although your own use may vary.

Answer (score 0):

If you're just talking about how to "mark it up" a bit nicer, you can just add a custom class to each image (or to the div around them) then add the css in an external style sheet. Something like:

```
<div class="arrow arrow1">
```

Then select it using:

```
.arrow.arrow1 img{
     top:13px; 
     left:-19px; 
     width:17px; 
     height:16px;
}
```

The goal though is not to have to use absolute positioning and to have to do too much "custom" stuff for each image, but when it's necessary you can use this method to keep the styles out of the html.

Comment: I was originally 'absolute positioning' everything, and it just felt wrong...I knew I'd probably end up redoing it all.  Yep!  I'm glad it's done correctly now, though!

Answer (score 0):

I interpret your Question as your wanting to have an **Arrow Overlay** on your images like this:

[image]

**HTML:**

```html
<div id="thumbnail1" class="clickDiv">Thumbnail 1
    <div class="arrowOverlay" ></div>
    <img src="http://lorempixel.com/200/200/sports/1" class="thumb" />
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```css
.clickDiv {
  position: relative;
  margin: 30px;
    /* The size of the DIV will be the thumnail image size plus borders on EACH side. */
  width: 204px;
  height: 204px;
  float: left;
}

.arrowOverlay {
  position:absolute;
  background:url("http://www.gravatar.com/avatar/106d65dcf622137346a5f164598985fa?s=64&d=identicon&r=PG") no-repeat center center;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  cursor: hand;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.thumb {
  width:  200px;
  height: 200px;
  /* Reminder: The border attribute as seen provides 2px per EACH side of the DIV. */
  border: 2px solid red;
}
```

**DEMO:**

[**jsFiddle Arrow Overlay**](http://jsfiddle.net/vUmJy/)